# Logical Volume Recovery after removal during reinstall

Tags: lvm, data-recovery

I had a 1TB disk with LVM running a server (Debian) since 2015. Later I added another 2 TB disk for home directories of students. Few days back I planned a reinstall. Plan was to remove all separate volumes for things like /usr etc and have a single root and another home volumes. My intention was to keep the home volume as it is and use it after reinstall.

To cut things short, I bypassed taking a backup. Booted debian installer and started deleting the logical volumes. Accidentally deleted the home LV. Immediately realized the mistake and didn't proceed with install. Meanwhile rebooted the system in rescue mode from the install media.

The question is - Is there any way to recover the home LV?

Comment: HDD or SSD? With SSD and `issue_discards=1` in lvm.conf, data would be gone. Otherwise restore from metadata backup (which LVM keeps in /etc/lvm/ as well as the on-disk header itself)

Comment: It's HDD. Please elaborate how may I recover the metadata from the disk header. As the root LV is also deleted and the system rebooted, I don't understand metadata backup from /etc/lvm/ as mentioned on many pages.

Comment: for a cursory check, `head -c 1M /dev/physicalvolume | strings -w -n 64` and see if that yields anything like `# Generated by LVM2`... you'll have to look out for timestamps as it might also have very old entries. you want the latest one that still had your home LV